# Changing MySQL Column collation with Alembic upgrade() script

Tags: python, alembic

Would like to change a Column collation from utf8mb4_unicode_ci to utf8mb4_bin

Its updated SqlAlchemy model is

```
col_name = Column(VARCHAR(10, collation='utf8mb4_bin'),  nullable=True)
```

I have tried

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa
import sqlalchemy.types as ty

def upgrade():

    op.alter_column('table_name',
        sa.Column('col_name', ty.VARCHAR(10, collation='utf8mb4_bin') )
    )
```

but the upgrade keeps the MySQL collation of that column to the original utf8mb4_unicode_ci

Comment: I posted an answer but then I read it was alembic while I am working with `sqlalchemy-migrate` and I deleted it. Maybe you got a notification from Stackoverflow. Sorry, in that case

Comment: No I didn't. I changed the content above according to last improvements but the problem remains unsolved

Comment: op.alter_column('table_name','col_name', type_=ty.VARCHAR(10, collation='utf8mb4_bin'))

Answer (score 2):

Found out the right syntax, i.e.:

```
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy.types as ty

def upgrade():

    op.alter_column('table_name','col_name', type_=ty.VARCHAR(10, collation='utf8mb4_bin'))
```

Comment: don't forget about `existing_type`, `existing_server_default`, and `existing_nullable` http://alembic.zzzcomputing.com/en/latest/ops.html#alembic.operations.Operations.alter_column